# Build Error after Upgrading microsoft.net.sdk.functions

Tags: c#, asp.net, build, nuget-package

My project uses .net framework 4.8. After upgrading microsoft.net.sdk.functions from version 1.0.24 to 3.0.1, the build on my local machine works fine, but there are some errors on the build on VSO pipeline:

> microsoft.net.sdk.functions\3.0.1\build\microsoft.net.sdk.functions.build.targets(41,5):
> It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
>
> The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.0.0' was
> not found
>
> microsoft.net.sdk.functions\3.0.1\build\microsoft.net.sdk.functions.build.targets(41,5):
> metadata generation failed.

There is no version 3.0.0 for Microsoft.NetCore.App nuget package. Why would the error ask for that version? Also how can I fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the package on NuGet, version 3.0.1 is intended for use with .NET Core 3.0 and higher applications, not .NET Framework applications.  Version 1.0.38 appears to be the latest version with .NET Framework support (4.6 and higher).

Answer (score 0):

**You can add the "Use .Net Core" task to the Agent job**

[image]

**And keep the setting applicable to your SDK version. Here it is 3.x**

[image]